# Regarding forward declaration in c

Tags: c, struct, forward-declaration

```
typedef struct treeNodeListCell {
    treeNode *node;
    struct treeNodeListCell *next;
}treeNodeListCell;

typedef struct treeNode{

    imgPos position;
    treeNodeListCell *next_possible_positions;

}treeNode;


typedef struct segment{
    treeNode *root;
}Segment;
```

I'm quite confused about forward declaration on the struct above,what is the way to use current declaration?

Answer (score 1):

So, from your example code, I understand you want to use `typedef`s for your `struct`s **and** you need forward declarations. The most straight forward (sic) way would be like this:

```
typedef struct treeNode treeNode;
typedef struct treeNodeListCell treeNodeListCell;
typedef struct segment segment;

struct treeNodeListCell {
    treeNode *node;
    treeNodeListCell *next;
};

struct treeNode {
    imgPos position;
    treeNodeListCell *next_possible_positions;
};

struct segment {
    treeNode *root;
};
```

Be careful when you use an older standard than [c11](/questions/tagged/c11). In that case, repeating the `typedef` is not allowed, so any forward-declaration in a different header must look like this

```
struct treeNode;
```

and then use `struct treeNode` instead of `treeNode` to refer to the type.

With [c11](/questions/tagged/c11), this restriction is finally gone and you can repeat a `typedef` if the defined type is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
typedef struct treeNodeListCell {
    struct treeNode *node;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    struct treeNodeListCell *next;
}treeNodeListCell;
```

In this case the type name `struct treeNode` is forward declared.

If the declaration looks like

```
typedef struct treeNodeListCell {
    treeNode *node;
    ^^^^^^^^
    struct treeNodeListCell *next;
}treeNodeListCell;
```

then the compiler can not know what `treeNode` means.

Comment: But `struct treeNode` is still not declared at this point,  isn't it?

Comment: @KeineLust No, it is declared but it is an incomplete type.